# How to hide background color in ReorderableListView

Tags: flutter

I've some problem with a ReorderableListView.
I want to remove the background from the dragged item (see image [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DyVSC.jpg)[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DyVSC.jpg)).
I've tried to add the Theme widget around the ReorderableListView to get rid of this issue.
It works but now I've a lighter border on cards sides (see [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JrBUx.jpg)[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JrBUx.jpg))
You can also try this issue in [DarPad](https://dartpad.dev/219942ec7286616c798f49765d08fc66)
Do you have any idea on how to solve it?

This is my code:

```
Expanded(
  child: Theme(
    data: ThemeData(canvasColor: Colors.transparent),
    child: ReorderableListView(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(16.0, 0.0, 16.0, 16.0),
      children: <Widget>[
        for (final items in homeButtons)
        Card(
          key: ValueKey(items),
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0)),
          child: Container(
            clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            height: 50.0,
            width: double.infinity,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              gradient: const LinearGradient(
                colors: [
                  Color(0xFF3b474f),
                  Color(0xFF232b32),
                ],
                stops: [0, 1],
                begin: AlignmentDirectional(1, -1),
                end: AlignmentDirectional(-1, 1),
              ),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
            ),
            child: ListTile(
              title: Text(
                '${items.toString().replaceAll('_', ' ')}',
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                style: GoogleFonts.outfit(
                  textStyle: const TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontSize: 18,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w100,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              leading: SvgPicture.asset(
                'assets/icons/$items.svg',
                color: Color(0xFFF0154B),
                height: 24.0,
                width: 24.0,
              ),
              trailing: Icon(
                Icons.navigate_next,
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
      onReorder: (oldIndex, newIndex) async {
        setState(() {
          if (newIndex > oldIndex) {
            newIndex -= 1;
          }
          final items = homeButtons.removeAt(oldIndex);
          homeButtons.insert(newIndex, items);
          box.remove(key);
          box.write(key, homeButtons);
        });
      },
    ),
  ),
),
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try below code and set `shadowColor`

```
Theme(
  data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
    canvasColor: Colors.transparent,
    shadowColor: Colors.transparent,
  ),
  child: ReorderableListView(),
),
```

Comment: Be aware that this also changes the canvas and shadow colors of all child widgets.

Answer (score 4):

According to [#45799](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/45799#issuecomment-943671663), you can solve this without overriding the Theme.

Create a new function:

```
import 'dart:ui';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

Widget proxyDecorator(Widget child, int index, Animation<double> animation) {
  return AnimatedBuilder(
    animation: animation,
    builder: (BuildContext context, Widget? child) {
      final double animValue = Curves.easeInOut.transform(animation.value);
      final double elevation = lerpDouble(0, 6, animValue)!;
      return Material(
        elevation: elevation,
        color: Colors.transparent,
        shadowColor: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.5),
        child: child,
      );
    },
    child: child,
  );
}
```

Then use it in ReorderableListView:

```
ReorderableListView(
  proxyDecorator: proxyDecorator(),
  // ...
)
```

You can tweak `color` and `shadowColor` to your liking.